# Extra spacing in strings with CDATA

Tags: android, html, xml, string, cdata

I need to display some strings that require both different font colors and arguments within.

I've been using `CDATA` within the string resources and `HtmlCompat.fromHtml` e.g

`<string name="my_string"><![CDATA[My string counts <font color="#FF544B">%s times</font> but sadly \n\n no spacing]]></string>`

`HtmlCompat.fromHtml(resources.getString(R.string.my_string, count), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)`

My problem is that `\n\n` doesn't create the **extra new line/spacing** I need.

I know I can solve this problem by having two different strings with two `TextViews` and add that spacing between them but there should be a way to add extra new lines/spacing within `[CDATA[...]]`, right?

Comment: Since you are using `HtmlCompat.fromHtml` what about `<br/>` instead `\n` ?

Comment: also "spacing" is misleading ... you should rather use "new line", as "spacing", in case of text, rather means horizontal (space, tabulator)

Comment: `<br/>` worked, thank you!